# Yank and put between two gvim instances in windows

Tags: windows, gvim, clipboard, yank

I frequently work with a couple of gvim instances in windows, usually also with several tabs in each instance. **Is is possible to have all the gvim instances share a common yank and put buffer**, so that I can yank in one instance and put what I just yanked in another instance?

Alternatively, is it possible to have gvim synchronise against the windows clipboard, such that everything I yank gets copied also, and when I put it will past from clipboard instead?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the system register *

so *y , and then paste as normal. This'll only work if gvim has clipboard support compiled in.

Comment: When I push * it immediately starts searching for what is under my cursor at the moment.

Comment: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Accessing_the_system_clipboard

Comment: @bjarkef: the '*' register is the clipboard. you yank to it via `"ay` ... read `:help registers` about how to access the registers and how to yank to and copy from one.